# Can't establish SQL Server connection from VS 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2008, connection

I am sorry if this sounds like a silly question, but I have googled for a while for a solution and no success. I am trying to establish a connection from VS 2008 to SQL Server. I am trying to use an user that my web application has been successfuly using to access the database from in its connection string. But when doing it from VS 2008, it tells me "Login failed  for use 'xxxxxx'". I am currently in the "Add Connection" window. I have chosen the datasource and server name, fulfilled username and password for SQL Server Authentication. Do I have to set specific permissions for this user? Do I need to allow a VS 2008 user in SQL Server? Thanks.

Comment: Is the database on the same server as the web application? If so, perhaps you aren't allowing remote connections.

Comment: If SQL Server and VS 2008 is on different workstations, you have to allow remote connections. Have you done that already?

Comment: If your database is on another machine, check these:
1. You must allow remote connection on machine running SQL Server.
2. Sometimes firewall in your machine or sql server machine may cause this problem.

Try connecting to sql server on your local machine, if you can, then the problem is from your connection, some thing such as these 2.

Comment: SQL Server and VS are in the same machine?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same machine

Comment: "Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Do you type correct instance name in Visual Studio? typicaly ".\SQLEXPRESS".

Comment: Hi, I have found what the problem was. It was exactly this. My Visual Studio would pull automatically something like MACHINENAME\SQLEXPRESS. As it was pulled automatically, I did not bother taking a closer look at it. I finally realized the connection string that worked for me in my other application was .\SQLESXPRESS. When I entered it in Visual Studio, it did work. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Since you've found a solution and it wasn't one of ours, can you please add it as a new solution and accept it? That way, this one is removed from the searches that return unanswered questions. Also, thanks for posting back the update!

Comment: Hey, OK, done it. Thanks for the advice. I am getting used to Stack Overflow and by the way, I love it.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution for this problem. My Visual Studio would pull automatically something like MACHINENAME\SQLEXPRESS. As it was pulled automatically, I did not bother taking a closer look at it. I finally realized the connection string that worked for me in my other application was .\SQLESXPRESS. When I entered it in Visual Studio, it did work. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have SQL Server Management Studio Express Installed?  if so try connecting as the same user through that interface.  This will isolate your problem a bit.

Comment: Yes, I do have it. I can connect in SQL Server Management Studio Express using this specific user, but cannot expand the Databases tree node.

Comment: Hum, sorry, now I can. I have changed some settings, trying to grant more rights to that user. I can log in SQL Server Management Studio Express, but still cannot log in from VS

Answer (score 0):

With Visual Studio, you're connecting through a "remote" connection, even though they're on the same machine. With Server Management Studio, you're connecting through a named pipe probably. You need to change the SQL configuration so that it allows remote connections. [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277) are instructions for how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have posted the solution I found above.

Answer (score 0):

You can test your SQL connection by connecting  using LINQPad, Often find this solves problems with connections to new SQL Server instances at my workplace.
http://www.linqpad.net/

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to specify the username and password to connect with in the connection string - ALA:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

This actually uses SQL Authentication, not Integrated (Windows) authentication. What you might be looking for is this:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

This would log into the database as the use running Visual Studio. Notice that the username/password aren't specified here - it uses the current Windows identity - in your case, that's the user running Visual Studio.

Comment: Just added a comment below my post: " Hi, I have found what the problem was. It was exactly this. My Visual Studio would pull automatically something like MACHINENAME\SQLEXPRESS. As it was pulled automatically, I did not bother taking a closer look at it. I finally realized the connection string that worked for me in my other application was .\SQLESXPRESS. When I entered it in Visual Studio, it did work. Thanks for the help anyway."